# Client Object Model equivalent of SPUtility.SendEmail in SharePoint 2010

Tags: email, client-object-model, silverlight, sputility

I am trying to send an email after an action occurs in Silverlight WebPart I am designing.

Is there a built-in class in the Client Object Model that can handle this, or will I have to build a custom web-service that wraps the SPUtility.SendEmail functionality?

Comment: I think the question was asked before. Did some digging and found [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92062/how-to-send-email-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-foundation). Hope this answers your question..

Comment: In cases where you find similar question on StackExchange already answered, you vote to close the question marking as duplicate and providing the link to the duplicate question you found :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I'm new to the community

Comment: On the question after the tags, do you options to share, edit close or flag?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of anything in the Client Object Model that lets you do this directly, but if you don't want to have to deploy a custom web service, you could probably make a list with a simple workflow that sends an email, and then just have your web part put an entry in the list and make sure it contains the columns you'll need to build the email message in the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Create the custom Web service then use it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such built-in functionality. In addition to two methods to achieve your goal from the similar thread provided by Falak Mahmood I can offer another one and easiest in my opinion. You can add an ASP.NET Ajax callback to your web part. Here's an example: http://ajaxzen.wordpress.com/tag/icallbackeventhandler/ Then you need only to call it from client code in your webpart and to use SPUtility.SendEmail in server-side callback handler. It's really a dozen lines of code and doesn't require such complex dependencies as custom webservice or special list with special workflow or event receiver or anything else.

Actually I did similar task myself with this method and it works perpectly. :)