# Send Email using Client side script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Client Object Model equivalent of SPUtility.SendEmail in SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16729/client-object-model-equivalent-of-sputility-sendemail-in-sharepoint-2010)

Hi EveryOne,
                Can anyone tell me how to send email using client side script like javascript and jquery with web services in SharePoint 2010.

Thanks

Comment: same question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16729/client-object-model-equivalent-of-sputility-sendemail-in-sharepoint-2010