# SPWeb is undefined

Tags: javascript, web-services, email, spweb, aspx

I am a newbie in sharepoint and only for 1 month. I am using sharepoint 2007,.aspx. and doing for an email form with some validation, after user pass the validation the email send.
But I'm getting the error `thisWeb is undefined`, I create this inside javascript function. I have SPUtility.js and I try to add line like `SPWeb thisWeb = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID;` and this causes my whole function not working. Do I need some .js for SPWeb? Please give me some instruction.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function notEmpty(){
    var txt="";
    var myTo= document.getElementById('txtTo2');
    var myName= document.getElementById('txtName2');
    var myFrom= document.getElementById('txtFrom2');
    var myBody= document.getElementById('txtBody2');
    var sendButton = document.getElementById('sendEmail');
    var validateButton = document.getElementById('button1');

    var body = ("This email is send from : "+ myName + ", Note here : " +myBody);

    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;


    if(myTo.value==""||myName.value==""||myFrom.value==""||myBody.value=="")
    {
        alert("Please Fill In All Fields!");
        return false;

    }
    else if(!(myTo.value.match(mailformat))||!(myFrom.value.match(mailformat)))
    {
        alert("Invalid Email Address!");
        return false;
    } 
    else if(myBody.value.length >5 )
    {
        alert("Please check body field! 5 characters only");
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        try
        {
            SPUtility.SendEmail(thisWeb, true, false, myTo, myFrom, body);                                                     
            alert(EmailSend!");
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n";
            txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
            txt+="Click OK to continue.\n\n";
            alert(txt);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

On SharePoint2007, you cannot access SharePoint object like SPWeb from JavaScript. Only on SharePoint 2010, the client object model was added that enables interaction with the SPWeb object (see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185008.aspx))

Specifically, the easiest solution for the problem of sending an email from client side code is wtriting an Ajax callback, the client code uses the callback and the server-side handler calls SPUtility.SendEmail. (See [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16729/client-object-model-equivalent-of-sputility-sendemail-in-sharepoint-2010) for more solutions)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, 
now I change my code to something like 
`protected void Btn_SendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.SendEmail(SPContext.Current.Web, true, false, toField, subject, body); ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock (this.GetType(), "confirm", "alert('Thank you. Your message has been successfully sent!')", true); } `and It working. Now other problems. It is an asp button. and everytimes I click ok for the validation, the page reload. How to make it not reload? thanks

Comment: Use Ajax. Otherwise, when using an ASP.NET button, a POST is sent which causes the page to reload.

Comment: Use [ASP.NET Update Panel](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax). Read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334289/asp-net-page-should-not-post-back-the-whole-page-on-submit) for more info.