# How to send email in SharePoint Hosted apps 2013 for SharePoint Foundation?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Did you know how can I send an email in my SharePoint Hosted apps? currently I am create a visual studio 2012 project for SharePoint 2013 foundation hosted apps with JavaScript code. I do not be able to send an email while user submit my request from. Please help, and kindly to comment or post for more detail information. noted that i need to use javascript and the REST API to send and email from a hosted app Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

This will only mail to users inside your SharePoint for security reasons, but does the job:

```
function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {

appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlTemplate,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'properties': {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
            'From': from,
            'To': { 'results': [to] },
            'Body': body,
            'Subject': subject
        }
    }
  ),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
       console.log('success')
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Is it can work on on-premise SharePoint?

Comment: I have used this for sharepoint hosted apps yes

Comment: I have test with O365 it working, but on my local share point seem not working, and on sharepoint hosted app client webpart also not working. I don't know y...

Comment: Make sure your outgoing mail settings are configured in Sharepoint General Administration > System Settings > Configure outgoing email.

Comment: Yes, I configure with smpt.gmail.com and smtp working properly..

Comment: I got this error message on O365 Client webpart, and really really don't know y https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9PMJN3pTJsSNVRQdlhxdmlxV0E/edit pls help

Comment: This worked for me Thank you very much . Is there any way to send meeting requests using this API?

Comment: Thanks for your code. It was very helpful. Can you please tell me where we can find this getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'). ? We have to explicitly define that or is it in built function ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: getQueryStringParameter() is a function that comes with the standard apps by default. If you started from scratch you can just copy paste it from here:
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
                var params =
                    document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
                    var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
                    if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
                        return singleParam[1];
                }
            }

Comment: Can a meeting request can be sent through same approach?

Comment: it really helpfull and working on sharepoint hosted apps. But it not working on sharePoint hosted apps Client webpart (it may permission cause). Any advise please share thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem as tola. I use the CSOM via C# and the E-Mail sending function only works on Office 365 SharePoints. On on-premises SharePoints it causes an Access Violation Exception. Is there any tip how to solve this?

Comment: It will work if you try to send it on Apps Page, not on Client Webpart.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Prem SharePoint, SharePoint online both Web and Hosted APP also.
If any error issue mostly with exchange/Email server send email policy. Some organization don't allow send email using program, user has to authenticated before sending email. But it works for internal email. That's sure.