# How do I create a form which sends an email?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I'm required to create a form which when submitted sends an approval/rejection email.

How would I go about doing this ?

Comment: See answer for this question (OP replies stating it works in O365): http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92062/how-to-send-email-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-foundation

Answer (score 2):

You can send an email using a SharePoint hosted app one of two ways:

You can simply [use javascript to make a REST call to SP.Utilities](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2d563e66-8777-4714-a238-b026c38ce37d/how-to-send-email-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-foundation?forum=sharepointdevelopment&prof=required):

```
function sendEmail() {

appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlTemplate,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'properties': {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
            'From': 'steve.curran@somewhere.com',
            'To': { 'results': ['smc750@somewhere.com'] },
                'Body': 'Hello',
                'Subject':'remember'
            }
    }
  ),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var result = data.d.results;
        var i = result.length;
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
}
```

Or you can [create a site workflow, and then use the following JavaScript to start the workflow](http://hasan-nasir.blogspot.com/2013/06/send-email-in-sharepoint-hosted-app.html):

```
function initWorkflowSubScriptionService() {  
    _wss = wfManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService();  
    context.load(_wss);  
    context.executeQueryAsync( 
    function (sender, args) {  
         subscription = _wss.getSubscription("f248e55e-495c-4c9b-b4de-618033d6be3b");  
         params = new Object();  
         params["argSubj"] = argSubj;  
         params["argBody"] = argBody;  
         params["argTOEmail"] = argTOEmail;  
         context.executeQueryAsync( function (sender, args) {  
             wfManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflow(subscription, params);  
             context.executeQueryAsync( 
                 function (sender, args) { },  
                 function (sender, args) {  
                 console.log("Something went wrong in starting workflow: " + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
                 }  
             )  
         })  
    },  
    function (sender, args) {  
     console.log("Something went wrong in starting workflow: " + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The System.Net.Mail namespace works with on-premise Sandbox solutions but does not work with Office 365, so there is no way to send email from code. The "Send Email" activitiy in SharePoint Designer workflows in Office 365 does work, so yes, you can use workflow to send email.

To send email with infopath form you can check:

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/225407.aspx

Comment: So is there no way to create a simple HTML based form and have it send any kind of email ?

Comment: Unfortunatly the workflow it self wont suffice. We have a lot of paper based processes which are going to be made electronic via sharepoint. So i'm assuming there isn't anyway of having a form submit its input to email ?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a custom form? You can use an approval workflow and create it in Sharepoint Designer. The template for the workflow is pre-defined and it's a very popular workflow so you will find plenty of tips and tutorials, eg.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-help/all-about-approval-workflows-HA102771433.aspx

You can customize the content of the email and you can set the workflow to start upon submitting an item to the SPO list. The item form can be customized as well.

Answer (score 0):

To send e-mail after form submission you can create SharePoint Designer workflow, which will be started on item creation.

Out of the box workflow action for Office 365 works, but it can't send messages to external recipients as well as attachments.

You can try to use 3rd party workflow action [Send e-mail with attachments](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/email-processing/) from [Workflow Actions Pack](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/).

You can read my [blog post](http://plumsail.blogspot.ru/2014/04/how-to-send-bulk-e-mail-with-attachment.html) to understand how to work with this workflow action. This post doesn't do exactly what you need, but you will get general understanding of how to use it.

Workflow Actions Pack is a paid but cheap enough solution developed by my team.