# How to send meeting request to user from sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, csom, sharepoint-email

I have a person field in SharePoint form and want to send outlook meeting request to person entered in Person field.

**Note:**I want to this through JQuery/JavaScript/SharePoint client object model only.

Comment: Following Url might help you.

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92062/how-to-send-email-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-foundation

Comment: Above url is for sending mail only. I need to create meeting request!

Comment: I tried using REST API SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail. It work for semding mail to user but I need meeting invites! Which is not happening!

Answer (score 1):

> The way to send a meeting request to Outlook (and have it recognized)
>   goes like this:
>
> prepare an iCalendar file, be sure to set these additional properties,
>   as Outlook needs them: UID SEQUENCE CREATED LAST-MODIFIED DTSTAMP
>   prepare a multipart/alternative mail: Part 1: text/html (or whatever
>   you like) - this is displayed to "ordinary" mail readers or as a
>   fall-back and contains a summary of the event in human readable form
>
> Part 2: text/calendar; method=REQUEST, holds the contents of the ics
>   file (the header method parameter must match the method in the ics).
>   Watch out for the correct text encoding, declaring a charset header
>   parameter won't hurt.
>
> Part 3: Optionally, attach the .ics file itself, so ordinary mail
>   readers can offer the user something to click on. Outlook does not
>   really require the attachment because it just reads the text/calendar
>   part.
>
> Send the mail to an outlook user. If you got everything right the mail
>   shows up as a meeting request, complete with attendance buttons and
>   automatic entry in the users calendar upon accept.

Look [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461889/sending-outlook-meeting-requests-without-outlook) for details.

As SharePoint has no services to send email message with custom structure, I believe it is not possible to send meeting invite via client API.
But if your organization use Exchange Server as mail server then you can use [EWS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495611(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Comment: :- I'm already doing that thing, using activexobject for IE and setting all the attributes in chrome. But it create only ics file correspondingly, i need to send it to user without server side object. Any possibility with SharePoint new REST API

Comment: If you can use outlook ActiveX APi why not to create appointment through it? Like in this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18689/Import-and-Export-Outlook-Appointments-using-JavaS)?

Comment: ActiveXObject feaislity is possible in IE only not in other browser. I need to send meeting invites through chrome where it only download ics file not send it. I can't use HTML5 too !