# Send Email when Sharing file/Folder

Tags: office-365, rest, share, sharepoint-email

Is it possible to send an email when sharing a file or folder through the REST API. Below is the screen I am referring to, I can share the file/folder. But would also like the option to send an email as well.
[image: Share File/Folder email]

If not through REST, are there any other methods through SharePoint

Answer (score 1):

below is the rest end point for sending email

```
/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail
```

It will only send email to internal users.

Source [How to send email in SharePoint Hosted apps 2013 for SharePoint Foundation?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92062/how-to-send-email-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-foundation)

Comment: thanks, will this send the email in format that is sent using the web ui?