# How can we send an email in sharepoint hosted app?

Tags: 2013

From a SharePoint hosted app, I want to send some emails in my sharepoint hosted app which will be deployed to office 365 tenants. Is there any code i can add in my app which will send emails to clients ? or maybe notifications ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use REST Endpoint `SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail` for sending mails in SharePoint Hosted app. Example:
Function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {

```
appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlTemplate,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'properties': {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
            'From': from,
            'To': { 'results': [to] },
            'Body': body,
            'Subject': subject
        }
    }
  ),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
       console.log('success')
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Source: [How to send email in SharePoint Hosted apps 2013 for SharePoint Foundation?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92062/how-to-send-email-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-foundation)