# Send email JavaScript SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-online, email

Is it possible to send an email in `PreSaveAction` function using JavaScript?

I tried [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92062/how-to-send-email-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-foundation) example. But it is not working.

Or is there a way to include the Email address provided in the NewForm to be added in the Workflow `SendEmail`?

**UPDATE**

I'm using SharePoint 2013 Online. And below is the code:

```
function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {
appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('https://url'));
alert(appweburl);
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('https://url/'));
var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlTemplate,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'properties': {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
            'From': from,
            'To': { 'results': [to] },
            'Body': body,
            'Subject': subject
        }
    }
  ),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
       console.log('success')
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Is email configured properly on your server? Can you post the code you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom list you can add a field to capture Email. Then inside the workflow you can sent email to `CurrentItem:Email`

Comment: I'm getting the Email from the People picker field under the PreSaveAction function. How to add it to the list?

Comment: I am confused. Isn't the field available in the new form?

Comment: The new form has a people picker field. From which I am getting the Email  address under the PreSaveAction function. There is no actual field for Email address.

Comment: Ok then why can't you add a new field for selecting people? Then in the workflow Sent Email to `CurrentItem:UserField` - Choose to return email

Comment: Super cool. I didn't know it was this simple.

Comment: Is it possible to start a workflow at a specified time?

Comment: @Keerthi please don't cross post. This will not help community who are looking for solutions to similar problem. Thanks for your understanding.