# SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail Change "From" display text

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, email

When sending emails via SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail, is it possible to change the From's display name so that it says something different rather than a title of the current site?

I'm fully aware of the fact that the from's email will always be **no-reply@sharepointonline.com**, but can I change the display name of it, at least?
[image]

**Here is the code I'm using:**

```
var subject = "SUBJECT OF THE MAIL";
var mailContent = "<h3>Some Heading for the mail</h3><p>Content</p><div>Content</div>";
var toList = ["usser5@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"]

//Send email message over REST
function sendMail(toList, subject, mailContent) {
    var restUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail",
    restHeaders = {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    mailObject = {
        'properties': {
            '__metadata': {
                'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
            },
            'To': {
                'results': toList
            },
            //'From': 'user@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"',
            'FromDisplay': 'Display From"', // <--- I want a property like this one
            // Important Note: this property does not work in SharePoint Online.
            // the <from> field will always be "no-reply@sharepointonline.com"
            'Subject': subject,
            'Body': mailContent,
            "AdditionalHeaders":
                {
                    "__metadata":
                    { "type": "Collection(SP.KeyValue)" },
                    "results":
                    [
                        {
                            "__metadata": {
                                "type": 'SP.KeyValue'
                            },
                            "Key": "content-type",
                            "Value": 'text/html',
                            "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                        }
                    ]
                }
        }
    };
    return $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: restUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(mailObject),
        headers: restHeaders
    });

} 

$(function(){
 sendMail(toList, subject, mailContent).then(function(data){console.log(data.d)})
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint Online it is impossible to set the **from** property when using the **SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail** method.

The **from:** field will always be no-reply@sharepointonline.com, and the description will be SharePoint Online.

Comment: This changed recently, instead of the Title of the web site, now the display name and address is: SharePoint Online <no-reply@sharepointonline.com>

Comment: thank you, @AlexFilipovici. I updated the answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

i am currently working on a similar problem and you can do it like this if you want to display a SharePoint user:

```
"properties" : {
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Utilities.EmailProperties"
    },
    "From": "username@domain", // <-- this one must be a SharePoint user 
    "Subject": "TestMail",
    "To": {
        "results": to
    },
    "Body": "Hallo Welt"
}
```

the result in outlook is the display name of the SharePoint User and `<no-replay@sharepointonline.com>` like the image below

[image]

And in an answer the to field will be the user.

Comment: you are probably using SharePoint on-premises, right? In this case you can use the "from" field. in SharePoint Online it's ignored.

Comment: No, I am using SharePoint online.

Comment: so does it work? When you look at the message in Outlook, what does the "From" field say?

Answer (score 0):

Thank to [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/153500/17341), I found a way to change the `From` and the `Reply` also. I tested it with Sharepoint 2013 On-Promise:

```
{
  'properties': {
    '__metadata': {
      'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
    }
    'AdditionalHeaders': {
      "__metadata": {
        "type":"Collection(SP.KeyValue)"
      },
      "results": [
        {
          "__metadata": {
            "type": 'SP.KeyValue'
          },
          "Key": "From:",
          "Value": 'My Title <some.email@example.com>', // here you can change the From
          "ValueType": "Edm.String"
        },
        {
          "__metadata": {
            "type": 'SP.KeyValue'
          },
          "Key": "Reply-To:",
          "Value": 'email@example.com', // when the user will hit the Reply button, this email will be used
          "ValueType": "Edm.String"
        }
      ]
    },
    'To': {
      'results': [username]
    },
    'Body': body,
    'Subject': subject
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid the question was about SharePoint Online. This won't work in SPO.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to modify anything in the “From” field of an email when using the `SendEmail` REST API in SharePoint Online.

### Testing

I’m including some code below so you can try this in your own environment. The `testSendEmail` function below takes the different headers you provide it and sends you emails with every combination (including the null combination) of those headers to see which make it through. This includes an example using the `From:`, `Reply-To:`, and `Sender:` headers.

```
async function testSendEmail(headers)
{
  const getDigest = async () => (
    (
      await (
        await fetch(
          _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
          { headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" }, method: "POST" }
        )
      ).json()
    ).d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
  );
  const reduceCombinations = (result, [key, value]) =>
  {
    const mapCombination = (include) => (combo) => ({ ...combo, ...(include ? { [key]: value } : {})});
    return [...result.map(mapCombination(false)), ...result.map(mapCombination(true))];
  };
  const sendEmail = (digest) => (headers) =>
  {
    const mapHeader = ([key, value]) => ({
      "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.KeyValue"
      },
      "Key": key,
      "Value": value,
      "ValueType": "Edm.String"
    });
    return fetch(
      _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail",
      {
        body: JSON.stringify({
          properties: {
            __metadata: { type: "SP.Utilities.EmailProperties" },
            AdditionalHeaders: {
              __metadata: { type: "Collection(SP.KeyValue)" },
              results: Object.entries(headers).map(mapHeader)
            },
            Body: `
              <p>Headers included:</p>
              <ul>${Object.keys(headers).map((key) => (`<li>${key}</li>`)).join("")}</ul>
            `,
            Subject: "SendEmail Test",
            To: { results: [_spPageContextInfo.userEmail] }
          }          
        }),
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": digest
        },
        method: "POST"
      }
    );
  };
  return Promise.all(Object.entries(headers).reduce(reduceCombinations, [{}]).map(sendEmail(await getDigest())));
}
testSendEmail({
  "From:": _spPageContext.userEmail,
  "Reply-To:": _spPageContext.userEmail,
  "Sender:": _spPageContext.userEmail,
  "X-SharePoint-Site": _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
}).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

### Conclusion

If you include any of the three problematic headers—`From:`, `Reply-To:`, or `Sender:`—in a REST API call to SharePoint Online, **all** your additional headers are removed. The headers have the intended effect in SharePoint 2013 on-prem and SharePoint 2016 on-prem.