# How to add HTML links in emails using CSOM?

Tags: email, jsom, hyperlink

I can send out email with HTML contents using the below code. But the a tag href links are being received as "[google.com]Link", instead of it being a clickable "Link".

```
    var data = {}; data.properties = {};
    data.properties.__metadata = { "type": "SP.Utilities.EmailProperties" };
    data.properties.To = { "results": [receipient] };
    data.properties.Subject = "Test email";
    data.properties.Body =
        "<h3>Some Heading for the mail</h3>" +
        "<p>Content</p><div>Content</div>" +
        "<a href='google.com'>Link</a><br/>";
    data.properties.AdditionalHeaders = {
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "Collection(SP.KeyValue)"
        },
        "results": [{
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
            },
            "Key": "content-type",
            "Value": "text/html",
            "ValueType": "Edm.String"
        }]
    }

    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var appWebUrl = GetUrlKeyValue("SPAppWebUrl", false, document.URL, false); 
    var url = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("X-RequestDigest", document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState != 4) { return; }
        var res = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        callback(null, res);
    }
    xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Edit:
To get above working, all I have to do is change "google.com" to "https://www.google.com"

Comment: checked this -  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150833/sp-utilities-utility-sendemail-with-additional-headers-javascript  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this code. It sends mail with clickable link in body.
**Note : Edit from and to variables.**

```
function processSendEmails() {

    var from = 'abc@domain.com',
        to = 'xyz@domain.com',
        body = '<a href="https://www.google.com">Test Visit google!</a>',
        subject = 'Hello World Subject, this is cool!!';

    // Call sendEmail function
    //
    sendEmail(from, to, body, subject);
}

function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {

    //Get the relative url of the site

    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;

    var urlTemplate = siteurl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({

      'properties': {
                     '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                     'From': from,
                     'To': { 'results': [to] },
                     'Body': body,
                     'Subject': subject,
                      "AdditionalHeaders":
                      {"__metadata":
                          {"type":"Collection(SP.KeyValue)"},
                          "results":
                          [ 
                              {               
                                  "__metadata": {"type": 'SP.KeyValue'},                                                                                               
                                  "Key": "X-Message-Flag",
                                  "Value": 'Follow up',
                                  "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                             },
                              {               
                                  "__metadata": {"type": 'SP.KeyValue'},                                                                                               
                                  "Key": "Reply-By",
                                  "Value": 'Wed, 23 Nov 2016 13:30:00 +0530',
                                  "ValueType": "Edm.DateTime"
                             }                            
                          ]
                      }
                }


        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Email Sent Successfully');
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert('Error in sending Email: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', processSendEmails);

});
```