# SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail send as plain text

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-email

I'm using the SendEmail JavaScript utility and it's working except that I'm getting the email as HTML instead of plain text (which is what I need to process the body correctly for another service). I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure out what. Here is my sendEmail function:

```
function sendEmail(subject,body) {
appweburl = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename";

var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlTemplate,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'properties': {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
            'From': 'address@company.com',
            'To': { 'results': ['otheraddress@company.com'] },
                'Body': body,
                'Subject': subject,
            "AdditionalHeaders":
            {"__metadata":
                {"type":"Collection(SP.KeyValue)"},
                "results":
                [ 
                    {               
                        "__metadata": {
                        "type": 'SP.KeyValue'
                    },
                        "Key": "Content-Type",
                        "Value": 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
                        "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                   }
                ]
            }
            }
    }
  ),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var result = data.d.results;
        var i = result.length;
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
}
```

How do I need to format the additionalheaders attribute to set the content-type header correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: A 2 minute search got me back here on StackOverflow: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150833/sp-utilities-utility-sendemail-with-additional-headers-javascript

Comment: Yes, I found that as well. It's what led me to write the content-type section the way I did. If you look through the comments on the answer, you will see that the original poster had the same issue I have... that no matter what content-type was sent it was still defaulting to text/html.

Comment: Since you are after a structured message (you say you need it for another service) why don't you put the data in the Header metadata..