# How to send mass emails with only BCC recipients but not To?

Tags: email, sharepoint-email, typescript, angular2

I am trying to send some subscription emails, need all the email addresses in `BCC`. I tried something like this

```
const requestUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail`;
const itemObject = {
    'properties': {
    '__metadata': {
        'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties',
    },
    'From': fromEmail,
    'To': {
        'results': [],
    },
    'BCC': {
        'results': toEmail,
    },
    'Body': body.replace(/\n/g, ''),
    'Subject': subject
    }
};
return this.getFormDigest().pipe(
    concatMap((formDigest) => {
        const headers = {
            'X-RequestDigest': formDigest.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
        };
        return this.restApi.post(requestUrl, '', '', itemObject, headers);
    })
);
```

But API fails with 400 Bad request

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found two good articles which covers sending emails in SharePoint using `SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail`.

Second link also covers sending Email with `AdditionalHeaders`.

**Sources**:

1. [Send email to distribution group stored in a SharePoint list using local email client](https://spjsblog.com/2012/06/12/send-email-to-distribution-group-stored-in-a-sharepoint-list-using-local-email-client/).
2. [SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail with additional headers [javascript]](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150833/sp-utilities-utility-sendemail-with-additional-headers-javascript).

**Update**: Please note below points before using `SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail`.

1. The recipient is limited to a valid SharePoint user for security reasons.
2. You have to add at least one user in `to` field to send an Email.
3. In SharePoint Online it is impossible to use `SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail` method and specify the `from` field. `from` field will always be `no-reply@sharepointonline.com`

Comment: Both are great examples, but both doesn't explain my problem, the thing is, Email sends (fine) if we provide at lease 1 To address, else fails.

Comment: try to add to To = "" (empty value)