# Send Email using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

In sharepoint hosted app how to send mail using js.I want send email to any user,not only for sharepoint user.

Answer (score 3):

You can mail SharePoint users from JavaScript via the REST interface (sample from [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92062/how-to-send-email-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-foundation)):

```
function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {

appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlTemplate,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'properties': {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
            'From': from,
            'To': { 'results': [to] },
            'Body': body,
            'Subject': subject
        }
    }
  ),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
       console.log('success')
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
}
```

As far as I know you can not do that for external e-mail addresses via the out-of-the-box solutions provided by SharePoint.

A possible workaround: You can implement your own E-Mail sender service, make it available via REST, and [call this interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj163088.aspx) from your SP hosted app.

Comment: This code is send mail to only sharepoint user.I want to send email to any user.

Comment: This 'minor' information was missing from your original question. As far as I know you can not do that via the solutions provided out-of-the-box by SharePoint.

Comment: SharePoint can only mail to AD contacts, If it could send to anyone in the world SharePoint would have been the number one Spam tool in the world.

Comment: so @Danny '365CSI' Engelman  is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman You can send to any email address using a 2010 workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this similar [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148226/send-e-mail-from-javascript-using-rest-api)

Note: As per @Danny commented, SharePoint can only mail to AD contacts.

Comment: this article is not work

Comment: It is a similar asked question and please refer given first answer which is also marked as true answer..

Comment: using SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail api Send mail to only SP users & I want to send mail to any user...

Comment: As i have written one note  "Note: As per @Danny commented, SharePoint can only mail to AD contacts"..  For security reasons the recipient is limited to a valid SharePoint user .

Comment: Using Sharepoint Hosted app I want to send mail to any user.It is possible or not?

Comment: 1. By using SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail, it's not possible.
2. By other methods shown in (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/879538/How-to-Send-Email-in-SharePoint-Provider-Hosted-Ap) , it can be possible.. refer "Using General Email Sending Method" section..